# How can I prevent one or more bones from being added to the key frame?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, keyframes

Is there a method to prevent keyframing a bone **even if it's selected**? It would really help to prevent mistakes or to just remember what bones should be included in an action.

Comment: If you don't want to key it, why is it selected? Can't you just hide it while animating, or am I missing something?

Comment: It COULD be selected by mistake. In the ideal scenario I would have a method to mark some bones so they are never included in keys (unless unmarked). This way I wouldn't have to remember what bones have to be part of an animation and I can give the model to someone else without having to give a list of bones that must be excluded from any animation.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I would suggest putting them on a bone layer for non-keyframe and disable it when keying. Or write a tiny script where you hardcode their names and clear their f-curves when done editing (would be horribly inflexible though)

Comment: That sounds more than reasonable. Will try this asap

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is locking the properties that you want to not change: Loc, Rot, Scale. You can see there are padlock icons for that. But I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly.